# What are the values of $g$ on $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-isomorphism, exact-sequence

I am trying to find a short exact sequence of the following form:

$$0 \to \mathbb Z_4 \xrightarrow{f} \mathbb Z_8 \oplus \mathbb Z_2 \xrightarrow{g} \mathbb Z_4 \to 0$$

I assumed that actually there is one and I am trying to put constraints on $f$ and $g$ that makes it exists. what I reached so far is that if $f$ is injective then the image of it will be one of the following $(\pm \bar{ 2}, \bar{0}),(\pm \bar{2}, \bar{1}).$ But then I want to use the surjectivity of $g$ to find the image of those elements and I hope that the image of one of them would be 0 and so it would be in the kernel of $g$ and so image g would be kernel f in this case  and I would have find the sequence I want. The problem that faces me is that:

What are the values of $g$ on $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$? so that I can express $(\pm \bar{ 2}, \bar{0}),(\pm \bar{2}, \bar{1})$ in terms of these two elements. could anyone help me in this please?

**EDIT:**

I also know that, If $\mathrm{ker}\ g=\mathrm{Im}\ f,$ then by the first isomorphism theorem applied to $g$, we would have
$$
\left(\mathbb Z_8 \oplus \mathbb Z_2\right)\ /\ \mathrm{Im}(f) \cong 
\mathbb Z_4,
$$ but how this will help me?

Comment: If the image of $f$ is $2\mathbb Z_8\oplus0$, so doesn’t involve the second summand, then the cokernel would be the direct sum $(\mathbb Z_8/2\mathbb Z_8)\oplus\mathbb Z_2$, which is not $\mathbb Z_4$. Therefore $f$ has to involve both summands.

Comment: Also, as $g$ is surjective, this must involve a surjection $\mathbb Z_8\to\mathbb Z_4$, so try sending a generator to a generator. Finally, there are only two maps $\mathbb Z_2\to\mathbb Z_4$, so you should be able to finish the construction.

Comment: yeah, I will write images of $f$ as a direct sum of the elements $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ I am asking about. for example $(2,1) = 2 (1,0) + (0,1)$@AndrewHubery

Comment: Yeah, I can send $(1,0)$ to $1$ but this will not work on g(2,1) if g(0,1) is 0 but it will work on g(2,1) if g(0,1) is 2 @AndrewHubery

Comment: So,  how can I know what is  g(0,1)? @AndrewHubery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(1)\in\mathbb Z_8\oplus\mathbb Z_2$ has order exactly $4$, so the $1$st component is $\pm2$. Without loss we may assume $f(1)=(2,x)$ for $x\in\mathbb Z_2$.

If $f(1)=(2,0)$ then $\mathrm{im}(f)=\ker(g)=2\mathbb Z_8\oplus0$, so $\mathbb Z_8\oplus\mathbb Z_2/\ker(g)\cong\mathbb Z_2\oplus\mathbb Z_2$, which is not $\mathbb Z_4$, so this is impossible.

Thus $f(1)=(2,1)$, where $\mathbb Z_8\oplus\mathbb Z_2/\ker(g)=\mathbb Z_8\oplus\mathbb Z_2/\langle(2,1)\rangle\cong\mathbb Z_4$, since $(1,0)$ has order $4$.

Now one choice for $g$ is $(1,0)\mapsto 1$ and $(0,1)\mapsto 2$ (so that $g\circ f(1)=g(2,1)=0$.)

Comment: Should not the generator be mapped into the generator in g? the problem that the generator of the domain of g is 2 elements not one element, how can we deal with this?

Comment: Is this the only choice for $g$ or are there other choices?

Comment: No, this is not the only choice. For example, $-g$ is an equally valid choice.

Comment: Yes I agree. but still I am confused because the generator of $Z_8 \oplus Z_2$ has 2 elements

Comment: I do not understand your concern; why are generators relevant? All we need is that $f$ is injective, $g$ is surjective, and that $\mathrm{im}(f)=\ker(g)$.

Comment: so we had four possible values of image $f$ and we excluded 2 and hence the remaining two will give us the values that is in the kernel of g

Comment: I think I see your point, but we understood that we should work on $(1,0)$ andd $(0,1)$ because they are the generators